# In flex how can someone add both bold and border?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder, mxml

I am trying to make a text area in flex 4.5. The problem  is i need some part of it as bold not all. Also i need border.

A simple code is

```
<s:TextArea text="Text here1     Text here2">
```

By default `s:TextArea` contain `border` but I cant bold only one part of text that is `"text here1"`

If I try to use `mx:TextArea` Then I cant add border to it.

Please if anyone can help over how to add border along with if i can make only a part of text as bold or of different color etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you add a border to `mxTextArea`? There are a couple of ways:

- specify `borderStyle` css property;
- write a skin class, which draws a border and background you need, and assign it to `borderSkin` css property;
- draw a 3x3 graphic skin and assign it to `borderSkin` css property.

Answer (score 0):

Place a border container around the control

Answer (score 0):

Use the textFlow property instead of the text property and you will be able to use rich text (bold, italics and so on).
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flashx/textLayout/elements/TextFlow.html